# How to detect the height of a cell having 2 columns row with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to build two text/image boxes next to each other, where one box defines the height of both on the desktop. In this case the first leftcol box should expand the background color to the size of rightcol and center the content. On mobile the boxes should not expand and just show one box in one row. I need some padding too to make this look good. This padding-right padding-left stuff feels wrong to get the content separated. Probably flexbox can handle this, but i currently dont get it.

```css
.leftcol {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #ff22aa
}
.rightcol {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    background-color: #aa4422

}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .leftcol, 
    .rightcol, 
    .boxes,
    div.boxes:nth-of-type(even),
    div.boxes:nth-of-type(odd){
        float: none;
        width: auto;
      padding: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="colgroup">
<div class="leftcol">
<h3>Bal</h3>
<p>blub blub</p>
</div>
<div class="rightcol">
<h3>Bla right</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I decided to reopen your question since I though it were wrongly closed by the other user, and post an answer for you. Let me know if that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that with Flexbox you could do like this.

See notes in the CSS

```css
.colgroup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;       /*  make a gap between when
                                            aligned side-by-side  */
}

.leftcol {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 15px);         /*  take of 15px for the gap  */
  background-color: #ff22aa
}

.rightcol {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 15px);
  background-color: #aa4422
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .colgroup {
    flex-direction: column;             /*  on mobile, stack them vertical instead  */
  }
  .rightcol {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="colgroup">
  <div class="leftcol">
    <h3>Bal</h3>
    <p>blub blub</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">
    <h3>Bla right</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```